# Spring & angular

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I use springmvc and spring security in backend and I want to use angular for front end.
that is my security config

```
    @Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/webjars/**", "/resources/**", "/public/**");
}

@Override
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login").permitAll().and()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/register").anonymous().and()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/ui/register_user").anonymous().and()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/register_user_step_2").anonymous().and()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/check_username").permitAll().and()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/register_complete").anonymous().and()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/index").permitAll().and()

            .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().hasRole("USER").and()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedPage("/login?authorization_error=true")
            .and()
            .csrf()
            .requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/oauth/authorize")).disable()
            .logout()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/index")
            .logoutUrl("/logout.do")
            .and()
            .sessionManagement().maximumSessions(1);
}
```

}

in frond end I want to change my state in user registration to show userRegistration.html page.

```
angular.module('app', [
'ui.router',
'ngResource',
'ui.bootstrap',
'ur.file'
]).config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
    $stateProvider
        .state('register', {
            template:  'userRegistration.html'
            controller: 'UserManagement'
        });

}).run(function ($rootScope, $log, $state) {

$rootScope.$state = $state;
var resolveDone = function () {
    $rootScope.doingResolve = false;
};
$rootScope.doingResolve = false;

$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (error) {
    $rootScope.doingResolve = true;
    $log.debug('State change started : ' + error);
});
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', resolveDone);
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (error) {
    $log.debug('State changed successfully : ' + error);
});

$rootScope.$on('$statePermissionError', resolveDone);
$rootScope.$on('$statePermissionError', function (error) {
    $log.debug('State permission error : ' + error);
});

}).controller('UserManagement', ["$scope", "$resource", "$state", function ($scope, $resource, $state) {
        $scope.register = function () {
            var registerCriteriaService = $resource(contextPath + '/ui/register_user', {}, {
                load: {method: 'GET'}
            });

        var registerCriteria = registerCriteriaService.load();
        registerCriteria.$promise.then(function (result) {
            $scope.banks = result.banks;
            $scope.registerInfo = result.registerInfo;
            $state.go('register');
        })
    }

}]);
```

but instead of show my template I catch this exception

```
GET http://localhost:8080/api/userRegistration.html 403 (Forbidden)
```

why it make a request to server?instead of loading my template.

I even change my spring security configuration and add "/userRegistration.htm" to ignore list

```
    @Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/webjars/**", "/resources/**", "/public/**", "/userRegistration.html");
}
```

and I get `GET http://localhost:8080/apiBanking/userRegistration.html 404 (Not Found)` error

How can I solve it to show my view.
thank you

Comment: is this `http://localhost:8080/apiBanking/userRegistration.html correct path` to your html?

Comment: userRegistration.html is beside of app.js. my question is why it make a request to server for loading template. evevn I change it to templateUrl:  '/resources/js/app/userRegistration.html', and get the same error 'GET http://localhost:8080/resources/js/app/userRegistration.html 404 (Not Found)'

Comment: Because it needs to check for permissions, you cant show something if its forbidden so probably your link in web.ignoring() is wrong. Try to add "js/**"

Comment: my js folder is inside of  /resources and I added '/resources/**' to web.ignoring(). I got 404 error not 403 for forbiden

Comment: in what folder is resources folder? This  `localhost:8080/resources/js/app/userRegistration.html`  is not good path

Comment: I set '/resource/**' in  web.ignoring() and my app folder (js files and all html template) is inside of it

Comment: you'er right. I added contexPath to it and I haven`t any error. but my html template did n`t load

Comment: yea i understand that but resource isnt your root folder, it is in something becouse `localhost:8080/resources/js/app/userRegistration.html` is wrong URL, try to change templateUrl to `templateUrl: apiBanking/resources/js/app/userRegistration.html` or: `templateUrl: resources/js/app/userRegistration.html` without / before resources. And its templateUrl not template

Comment: TemplateUrl:contexpath+"/resources/js/app/userRegistration.html" now i havenot any error but it didnot load my template

Comment: add url in your state...

`.state('register', {
            url: '/register',
            templateUrl: contexpath+ 'userRegistration.html',
            controller: 'UserManagement'
        });`

...then try that URL in browser

Comment: Please refer this link. This is combination of angularJS+spring-security. It worked for me   https://github.com/philipsorst/angular-rest-springsecurity

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you watch a [jhipser](https://jhipster.github.io/) generator project. This is exactly what you want to use (backend with SpringMVC/springsecurity and frontend with angularjs and security). An example of generated site jhipster : [example](http://www.tests-psychotechniques.fr)